# finding a specific document using one of the fieds from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app (react-native) I am making a search query that finds a specific document based on one of the documents fields, it is a barcode that can be scanned, and then using the scanned value want to look for the object in the firebase, every object has the field that holds the value for the barcode. I just want to find it.

I followed this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#node.js).

this is what I have currently:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    saveData();
  }, []);

const saveData = async () => {
    const productRef = db.collection("products");
    const queryRef = await productRef.where("barCode", "==", data).get();
    console.log(queryRef);
}
```

but this doesn't return the correct result, what am I missing?

this is the screenshot of console log but at the end I have this:

> (truncated to the first 10000 characters)

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also provide us the value of `data` inside the where() call. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Where is the `data` coming from? Can you `console.log(data)` right before the query and check if it matches the `barCode` in your Firestore document ? Also the field names are case sensitive so make sure that's correct.

Comment: @AlexMamo for products I have several fields each field containing some data, including the scanned bar code

Comment: @Dharmaraj I am getting the correct scanned data, I want to find that in the firebase now

Comment: Then please share a screenshot of your document. Also can you share as screenshot of the logged output? The 'tutorial' has no barCode thing so it's hard to make an assumption as well.

Comment: "but this doesn't return the correct result" => What does it return?

Comment: You are indeed logging the querySnapshot... try this `console.log(queryRef.docs.map(d => d.data()))` which will log an array of matched documents

Comment: @Dharmaraj I think this is it. not in the log I can see the product I was looking for.

Comment: @Dharmaraj how can I save this to a local object?

Comment: You can set it in state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const queryRef = await productRef.where("barCode", "==", data).get();
```

This query returns a QuerySnapshot which has a `docs` property that is an array of DocumentSnapshot. You can them map a new array containing the data from documents and set it in state:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

const saveData = async () => {
    const productRef = db.collection("products");
    const queryRef = await productRef.where("barCode", "==", data).get();
    setProducts(queryRef.doc.map(d => ({id: d.id, ...d.data()})));
}
```